# Impossible select dvd drive from mac book pro

Tags: dvd

I have installed a new drive (SSD) on mac book pro (early 2011) and installed Linux Mint without macOS. Something appear to be wrong because I can't access to the DVD drive from the boot, every time I am on the system. 
The simple question is how to select the dvd drive as first from the boot manager (efi).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a CD/DVD to be default boot, because you can't 'bless' it.

To boot from an optical disk, hold  <kbd>C</kbd>  at the boot chimes, or  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  to see all bootable partitions.

Comment: Nothing to do. Those commands doesn't works at all.

Comment: What does happen? Please don't turn this into 20 questions. Give information. Try Cmd/R too & let us know what result you get.

Comment: Well, after doing as you have indicated I am very disappointed . Every time I try I feel the dvd working but nothing happen and I get the welcome page of Linux Mint where I have to insert my password to get in, but any other menu to choose a different drive. I believe that the last choice is to remove the ssd and reinstall again to see if a problem is with it.

Comment: I have found the main problem. The keyboard was in short circuit then I couldn't make anything. I discover this issue just testing connections on the hardware keyboard. Sorry for the waste question I have done, but I didn't know the matter I have got.